# Jquery each, how to not take broken urls?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to not take images with broken url?

```
jQuery.each(jQuery('img'), function(k, o) {
imageStack.push(jQuery(o));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Only push the images whose [`load` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) has fired to `imageStack`.

To do this, you can bind a `load` event listener to every image which pushes the image to `imageStack`.

```js
const imageStack = []

$('img').on('load', function() {
  imageStack.push($(this));
})

$(window).on('load', function(){
 //wait for every image to load, so imageStack will contain every loaded image
  console.log(imageStack)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1">
<img src="brokenurl">
```

Alternatively, you can wait for every image to load by listening for the [window `load` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event), then check the image's [`naturalWidth` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/naturalWidth):

```js
const imageStack = []

$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('img').each(function() {
    if (this.naturalWidth != 0) {
      imageStack.push($(this));
    }
  })
  console.log(imageStack)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1">
<img src="brokenurl">
```

Comment: I'm use this code in Chrome extension, when change my code on your after run script images not found :(

Comment: @RT Try the second option in my answer.

Comment: something goes wrong

Comment: console is empty